# Ein Punkt, an dem ich ernst zweifle

Tags: punctuation

Könnten Sie mir sagen, ob dieser Punkt notwendig und verbindlich ist oder ob er sogar inkorrekt ist? Ich meine das Folgende: Können Sie mir sagen, welcher Satz richtig ist?

1. Mein Opa sagte: "Wo ist mein felliges Kätzchen?"**.** Danach bin ich in den Wald das Kätzchen suchen gegangen.
2. Mein Opa sagte: "Wo ist mein felliges Kätzchen?" Danach bin ich in den Wald das Kätzchen suchen gegangen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Anführungszeichen stehen am Anfang und am Ende von etwas wörtlich wiedergegebenem. Eine andere Funktion als Satzzeichen haben sie nicht.

Daher müssen alle übrigen Satzzeichenfunktionen (in deinem Beispiel: Das Beenden eines Ganzsatzes) durch weitere Satzzeichen übernommen werden. Das gilt für Frage- und Ausrufezeichen. Einen Punkt am Ende des Ganzsatzes direkt nach dem schließenden Anführungszeichen soll man weglassen (§92).
[Regelwerk des Rechtschreibrats §90ff](https://www.rechtschreibrat.com/DOX/rfdr_Regeln_2016_redigiert_2018.pdf)